# What is the purpose of the specialized subtitles during "The Boogeyman" song?

Tags: analysis, subtitles, john-wick

In [*John Wick*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2911666/) (2014), during the scene right before Viggo's men attack John at his house, we see Viggo singing some kind of nursery rhyme about "The Boogeyman" in another language. The subtitles show the translation but some of the words are highlighted and stylistically different than the rest of the subtitles. What is the purpose of this? I wouldn't have been quite as curious about this if only "The Boogeyman" was different but the word "take" is changed as well which seems random to me.

So why were these words shown differently in the subtitles?

Note that this stylistic subtitle method is repeated throughout the film. Some words that are highlighted later in the film: Sixty, Impressive, Stole, You Killed, Here!, Building! I am specifically interested in what the emphasis is meant in this specific part of the film though.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you had noticed, there are two words that are highlighted in the song's subtitles, **The Boogeyman** and **Take**.

According to legend as we used to hear, The boogeyman punishes children for bad behavior.

John wick resembles to him as he is ahead of the curve when it comes to being bad. He thinks what is his, he will **take** it, even if it means someone's life.

Scriptwriters wanted to make it clear that his skill was on a legendary level and that he could kill and be worse than your biggest fears (**The Boogeyman**).

[Source](https://www.quora.com/Why-are-the-words-The-Boogeyman-and-Take-highlighted-in-the-movie-John-Wick)

Comment: I'm not sure that Quora is a very authoritative source, since it's basically an alternative to Stack Exchange. Are there any more authoritative sources to back up your strong claim that this was definitively what the scriptwriters intended (and not what we *think* they intended)?